# How to add missing dates in dataframe and fill the other corresponding columns in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
   id           Date     number
0  1Y     2005-01-07        1.0
1  1Y     2008-01-07        1.6
2  5Y     2005-01-07        1.0
3  5Y     2008-01-07        1.7
4  6Y     2005-01-07        6.0
5  6Y     2008-01-07        1.0
6  10Y    2005-01-07        2.0
7  10Y    2008-01-07        7.1
8  30Y    2005-01-07        5.5
9  30Y    2008-01-07        8.6
...
```

And I would like to add dates in the date column with the missing dates (day by day) up to today for each  `id`.

I tried

```
df.set_index(df.Date, inplace=True)
df.resample('D').ffill().reset_index()
```

But I cannot achieve the output I described.

Also, if possible, assuming the corresponding number of the added dates is  `NaN`, I would like to assign these `NaN` to be equal to the number directly above it.

Desired output:

```
   id           Date             number
0  1Y     2005-01-07                1.0
0  1Y     in between dates          1.0
1  1Y     2008-01-07                1.6
1  1Y     dates after               1.6

2  5Y     2005-01-07                1.0
2  5Y     in between dates          1.0
3  5Y     2008-01-07                1.7
3  5Y     dates after               1.7
...
8  30Y    2005-01-07                5.5
8  30Y    in between dates          1.0
9  30Y    2008-01-07                8.6
9  30Y    dates after               1.7
```

---

Another way of illustrating the problem can be:
I can also rewrite the dataframe as the following:

```
   id    2005-01-07   2008-01-07    ...
0  1Y           1.0          1.6
1  5Y           1.0          1.7
2  6Y           6.0          1.0
3  10Y          2.0          7.1
4  30Y          5.5          8.6
```

And I wanted to achieve :

```
   id    2005-01-07   Date missing    2008-01-07    ...    Date today
0  1Y           1.0            NaN           1.6                  NaN
1  5Y           1.0            NaN           1.7                  NaN
2  6Y           6.0            NaN           1.0                  NaN
3  10Y          2.0            NaN           7.1                  NaN
4  30Y          5.5            NaN           8.6                  NaN
```

And then fill the NaN with the existing numbers on the left.

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, it sounds like you can use [combine](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine.html) method in Pandas

Comment: can you test `df1 = df.groupby(['id'],as_index=False).resample('D').ffill()`

Comment: @Datanovice I get an error message, "only valid with DatetimeIndex TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Int64Index'

Comment: ah I thought you added the Date to the index. `df.set_index(df.Date, inplace=True)` also make sure its a datetime `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`

Comment: @Datanovice oh yes if forgot the `.set_index`. Yes, Date.dtype is datetime (I just didn't put the time part in the example just to simply).
This is working but is filling all dates until the last date in my original df `max(df.date)`. How can I make it to fill to today's date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I understand now,

first we need to add in today's date to your current dataframe based on each ID. then apply the groupby and resample operation.

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s+')
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df1 = pd.concat(
    [df, df[["id"]].drop_duplicates().assign(Date=pd.Timestamp("today").normalize())]
)
df1 = df1.set_index("Date")

df2 = df1.groupby(['id'],as_index=False).resample('D').bfill().ffill().reset_index(1)
```

---

```
df2[df2['id'] == '1Y']['Date'].max()
Timestamp('2020-05-21 00:00:00')
```

Comment: it works, but with one issue. Happening only for the date of today "2020-05-21" the values are not being filled, they are NaN.

Comment: `bfill` worked, except for the last element of the dataframe, this one still is NaN

Comment: So if you reverse the order of `.ffill().bfill()` to `.bfill().ffill()` the problem of the last element is solved.